# Create Github repository from java

Tags: java, git, github, integration, jgit

I need to create remote Github repository using java (Using my credentials) and I need to push some code to that repo.

I saw some examples using JGit and some other references like 
http://www.codeaffine.com/2015/11/30/jgit-clone-repository/  and https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api.

But I'm not able to understand fully.

```
// ------------ create the directory ---------
try (Git git = Git.init().setDirectory(localPath).call()) {
  System.out.println("Having repository: " + git.getRepository().getDirectory());
}
```

I tried this one. I can only create repo in local.
So How can I push these changes to remote.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to create a repository on GitHub, you need to use something that talks to the GitHub API like the lib of Kohsuke you linked to, or you need to talk to the API directly if you prefer.

If you also want to create a local Git repostory and push that to the remote, you additionally need to use e. g. JGit to either clone the repository you created or create a new repository, set the remote configuration to the repo created on GitHub and then push.